# Codeigniter database queries with multiple LIKE parameters

Tags: sql, codeigniter

How can I perform a query with multiple LIKE parameters?

For example, I have this string to search through:

```
"I like searching very much"
```

This is the code I currently use:

```
$searTerm = "like"
$this->db->or_like('list.description', $SearchTerm,'both');
```

But i want to search with 2 or 3 parameters. like this:

```
$searTerm = "like"
$searTerm1 = "much"
```

How can i perform this to get the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply repeat the `like` parameters on the active record. In your example you would do something like this:

```
$this->db->or_like('list.description', $searchTerm1);
$this->db->or_like('list.description', $searchTerm2);
$this->db->or_like('list.description', $searchTerm3);
...
```

This will just join each `or_like` with an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to define the array with like variables then, its very important to put the `or_like` statement above the `where` clause in order to make multiple 'OR' statements for `like` 'AND' the where clause.

Here is example:

```
$this->db->or_like(array('column_name1' => $k, 'column_name2' => $k))
$this->db->where($whereColumn, $whereValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like group

```
            $this->db->group_start()->like('column_name1', $value)
            ->or_group_start()
            ->like('column_name2', $value)
            ->group_end()
            ->group_end();
```